# Use Old (Pre-Whisker) Xfce Menu?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

Is there a way to install the "old" XFCE application menu? Specifically, the one shown in the screenshot here (which I beleive was the default until it was replaced by Whisker, in Xubuntu 14.04): https://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-graphically-edit-xfcexubuntu.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try the application menu in the add to panel menu? as seen here https://imgur.com/8Jr2hDa.png

Comment: results in https://imgur.com/DSQBhNk.png as also noted by @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally use the option "Move" to place it where you want.

Comment: was just asking about this minutes ago... maybe you should point out how to remove the word "Applications" aswell since the OP didn't spot the obvious...

Comment: Ah, perfect!  Accepted.